# Trigger UICollectionViewCell press on UIControlEventTouchDown event instead of UIControlEventTouchUpInside?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicontrolevents

I have a UICollectionView with 35 square UICollectionViewCells. Upon pressing them, an audio file is played. I cannot however press two or more cells at the same time because the audio file is triggered once my finger leaves the button (i.e. `UIEventTouchUpInside`), and seems to lock me out of pressing any other cells until the touch up inside event is completed.

Is there a way to change the default way in which a UICollectionViewCell handles touch events so that it can trigger them on a `UIControlEventTouchDown` instead of a `UIControlEventTouchUpInside` event?

Answer (score 0):

You can try overriding `-(void) setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted` and play the sound there.